# Is it possible to extract Android menu settings from other apps installed on the phone?

Tags: android, menu, settings

I'm working on a bug reporting app and I need to be able to access the settings values of other apps. I need to know if users have changed the settings of other apps and what they've changed them to. Is there a way to determine the settings of other installed apps?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless they are set to be read by other apps, reading other application settings would constitute a security flaw (they can hold passwords...)